# How can I add items to a ComboBox (or other Control) using FXML?

Tags: javafx, controls, fxml

Recently, I discovered that `<ComboBox>`—and other controls—can have an `<items>` element underneath them .

How can I populate, or add items right to a control in the FXML markup?

(One use case for this might be to make the FXML semi-functional as a mockup to show to stakeholders.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Research proves that it's done with a combination of the `fx:value` and `fx:factory` attributes. These seem to have been added in <del>[JavaFX 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html)</del> [JavaFX 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html).

Below, I'll cite the mechanisms and then give some examples.

#### Warning:

Note, as @fabian does, that though this works well in the short term for something like a prototype or mockup, adding items directly to the FXML *breaks* the separation between *model* and *view*—and that may likely be an undesired result in the long term.

## The Mechanisms

> ### fx:value
>
> The fx:value attribute can be used to initialize an instance of a type that does not have a default constructor but provides a static valueOf(String) method. For example, java.lang.String as well as each of the primitive wrapper types define a valueOf() method and can be constructed in FXML as follows:
>
> ```xml
> <String fx:value="Hello, World!"/>
> <Double fx:value="1.0"/>
> <Boolean fx:value="false"/>
> ```
>
> Custom classes that define a static valueOf(String) method can also be constructed this way.

Source: [JavaFX 2 Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements)

---

> ### fx:factory
>
> The fx:factory attribute is another means of creating objects whose classes do not have a default constructor. The value of the attribute is the name of a static, no-arg factory method for producing class instances. For example, the following markup creates an instance of an observable array list, populated with three string values:
>
> ```xml
> <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
>     <String fx:value="A"/>
>     <String fx:value="B"/>
>     <String fx:value="C"/>
> </FXCollections>
> ```

Source: [JavaFX 2 Introduction to FXML](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements)

---

## Some Examples:

#### ComboBox

```xml
<ComboBox value="One">
    <items>
       <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <String fx:value="Three"/>
            <String fx:value="Two"/>
            <String fx:value="One"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</ComboBox>
```

[image: ComboBox in FXML with default value]

#### CheckComboBox

The [ControlsFX](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/) Controls are a little different:

```xml
<CheckComboBox>
    <items>
        <String fx:value="One"/>
        <String fx:value="Two"/>
        <String fx:value="Three"/>
    </items>
</CheckComboBox>
```

[image: checkcombobox]

#### [TableView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/fxml_get_started/fxml_tutorial_intermediate.htm)

TableView gets a little more complicated because it needs [`CellValueFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#cellValueFactoryProperty)s to know which part of the Person to show in each column.

```xml
<TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn text="Name">
        <cellValueFactory>
            <PropertyValueFactory property="name" />
        </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn text="Comment">
        <cellValueFactory>
            <PropertyValueFactory property="comment" />
        </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>  
    <items>
        <FXCollections fx:factory="observableArrayList">
            <Person name="Jacob" comment="Hey!"/>
            <Person name="Isabella" comment="Dude, we're in FXML!"/>
            <Person name="Ethan" comment="No way!"/>
        </FXCollections>
    </items>
</TableView>
```

[image: TableView in FXML]

Comment: They were available before, see https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html . Also [the section **](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#class_instance_elements) lists a lot more ways to create instances than `fx:factory`/`fx:value`. In fact you do use one of these possibilities in the last code snippet. Also doing this you can be sure that you break any separation between model and view...